# How to "Sum" EF 6 migrations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

My project has many migrations. To be precise, there are 35. Now that we're going for version 1.0 I want to "sum" these 35 migrations into a single migration for ease of control.
How can I do that?
How can I generate a aggregate of all these migrations as if I have never created a previous migration?

Details:

- EF 6
- Using Code First
- Automatic Migrations: False

Deleting the previous migrations and trying to "Add-Migration" does not work... neither does rolling back the database to target migration 0... Is there a flag such as "Ignore Previous Migrations"?

Comment: You can call Update-Database -Script -–TargetMigration:XXX which will create a SQL script of the migrations from the DB's current state to migration XXX. Is that what you need?

Comment: I'd call this "collapsing" migrations.  Going from 35 to 1.  Here's a possible dupe, which I think is correct http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789065/what-is-the-best-way-to-collapse-all-existing-enityt-framework-migrations I think, in addition to deleting all code migrations, you may have to remove the history from the database migration table as well.  But I'm not sure; EF might take care of that for you.

Comment: @Matt, actually no, i need a migration, not a script... I need the class with the create tables and etc to later run the update-database...

Comment: I guess you could write your own migration generator. http://romiller.com/2012/11/30/code-first-migrations-customizing-scaffolded-code/

Comment: Are you deleting the _MigrationHistory records as well? I've done this several times using this technique. http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/#at_pco=smlwn-1.0&at_si=54ad5c7b61c48943&at_ab=per-12&at_pos=0&at_tot=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Rollback your database (Update-Database -TargetMigration 0)
2. Delete all migrations
3. Recompile everything (very important!!! Spent about 15min on "explicit migration pending...")
4. Add new migration!